# Using FirstLogonCommands in an Unattend.xml file

Tags: windows, deployment, unattended, mdt

I apologize ahead of time for what is probably a stupid question, but I'm having a hard time figuring this out from the Microsoft Documentation (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-firstlogoncommands):

If I populate my Unattend.xml file with the 'FirstLogonCommands' setting at the oobeSystem pass, will the commands run once for the first user that logs into the machine, or will the command run once for each user that logs into the machine?

Answer (score 2):

The command(s) will run once for the first user that logs into the system.

Think about it. If you add a user a year down the road, the commands do not execute on the original login of that user. The command only runs on the first login of the first user after deployment.

Take a look here for examples:
https://serverfault.com/a/814423/216286